# Write reference of linenumber to file

Tags: line-numbering, write, write-file

I want to write the actual linenumbers that a `\lineref` command generates into an external file. The lines are referenced correctly (after 2 times compiling), but the writing to a file does not work. Here is my MWE, with my (humble) try uncommented to illustrate what I want to do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\newwrite\tempfile

\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\tempfile=fooref.tex
\begin{linenumbers}*
foo \linelabel{lne:foo1} foo

foo \linelabel{lne:foo2} foo
\end{linenumbers}
\lineref{lne:foo1}
\lineref{lne:foo2}

%\immediate\write\tempfile{\lineref{lne:foo1}} % <- how to do it??
%\immediate\write\tempfile{\lineref{lne:foo2}} % <- how to do it??

\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\end{document}
```

The resulting fooref.tex should contain just the linenumbers:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you'll do with this file, but here's a way to accomplish your need:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lineno,refcount}

\newwrite\linenumbersfile
\newcommand{\writelineref}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\linenumbersfile{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\linenumbersfile=\jobname.num
\begin{linenumbers}*
foo \linelabel{lne:foo1} foo

foo \linelabel{lne:foo2} foo
\end{linenumbers}
\lineref{lne:foo1}
\lineref{lne:foo2}

\writelineref{lne:foo1}
\writelineref{lne:foo2}

\immediate\closeout\linenumbersfile
\end{document}
```

I changed the naming scheme, in order to avoid clobbering files. Correct annotations in the `.num` file requires two LaTeX runs, as usual when references are dealt with. With `\getrefnumber` we ensure expandability of the reference.

The `.num` file contains

```
1
2
```

as requested.

Comment: Great, thanks, that works for me. I am writing a tag-macro so that I can tag several lines of text, write them into a file and also get the corresponding linenumbers (e.g. "lines 5 to 7"). With that I start working in Excel.